# Closed set that is not complete

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples, complete-spaces

Can anyone help me out with an example of a closed set that is not complete? I have read up on the set of irrational numbers with the euclidean metric is such an example on other web pages, but that does not make any sense to me since the set of irrational numbers with the euclidean metric in not closed to begin with

Comment: A closed subset of a complete metric space is necessarily complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the set $\Bbb I$ of irrational numbers is an example. It is a closed subset of itself and it is not complete (with respect to the usual distance).

On the other hand, every closed subset of a complete metric space is always complete.

Comment: Forgive me for my ignorance,but what about the sequence (√2/n) which is an irrational sequence ,but it converges to 0(w.r.t usual metric) which is not an irrational number?

Comment: That sequence does *not* converge in $\Bbb I$.

Comment: Thank you so much @José Carlos Santos!

Comment: I have a follow up question @José Carlos Santos which I hope you won't mind having a look at,please. Does your above answer change if we consider the set or irrationals as a subset of the reals with the usual metric?Instead of looking at the irrationals as a metric space on its own with the usual metric?

Comment: Yes, it changes, since $\mathbb I$ is not a closed dubset of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Okay thank you @José Carlos Santos. I should have phrased my initial question better because I was looking for help with finding an example of a closed subset that is not complete in an arbitrary metric space. This why I was confused about the case of saying the irrationals is such an example when I read the other web pages.

Comment: There is no such example. Every complete subset of a metric space is closed.